# SQL Query: Output in base table and add the aggregate as an extra line

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm helping a friend with a SQL exercise sheet. He needs to compute a sum query (with some intermediate steps) and then output the base table **together** with the final aggregate in the last line. The final result should look like this:

[image]

We can already get the first 6 lines with this query:

```
Select AP.AUFNR, K.FIRMA, AP.MENGE, AP.PREIS AS EINZELPREIS, AT.ARTBEZ,(AP.MENGE*AP.PREIS) AS AUFTRAGSWERT
From kdst k, aufpos ap, artst at, aufkopf ak
Where k.KDNR=ak.KDNR
and ak.AUFNR=ap.AUFNR
and ap.ARTNR=at.ARTNR
and AP.MENGEGEl = 0
Order By AUFNR, Menge;
```

And we can already get the aggregate with this query:

```
Select Sum(AP.MENGE*AP.PREIS) AS AUFTRAGSWERT
From kdst k, aufpos ap, artst at, aufkopf ak
Where k.KDNR=ak.KDNR
and ak.AUFNR=ap.AUFNR
and ap.ARTNR=at.ARTNR
and AP.MENGEGEl = 0;
```

However, how is it possible to unite both in a single table with such default null values in the row containing the aggregate? Maybe some kind of manipulation in order to add the missing attribute values to the aggregate row and then use a `UNION`?

I have never seen an exercise like this...

The PDF containing the database can be found [here](https://docdro.id/QsLNFhj).

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Which dbms is your friend using?

Comment: Oracle, sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-rollup/